# How to add scroll bar on my webpage when i resize my browser?

Tags: html, css

why if i re-size down my browser, there's no available scroll up and down to view the full content of the page?

[image]

here is my Html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><title>Faceboo Practice</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head> 
<body>
    <div class="header">
        <div id="faceboo_logo" class="header">Faceboo
        </div>
        <div id="form1" class="header">Email or Phone?<br>
            <input type="email" placeholder="email"/>
        </div>
        <div id="form2" class="header">Password<br>
            <input type="Password" placeholder="Password"/><br>
            Forgot password?
        </div>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" class="submit1" value="login"/>
    <div class="body1">
        <div id="left_content1" class="body1">Faceboo helps you connect and share with the people in universities</div>
        <div id="left_content2" class="body1">Create Account</div>
        <div id="left_content3" class="body1">It’s free and always will be.</div>
        <div id="form3" class="body1">
            <input placeholder="First Name" type="text" id="namebox" />
            <input placeholder="Last Name" type="text" id="namebox" /><br>
            <input placeholder="Mobile Number or Email" type="text" id="emailbox" /><br>
            <input placeholder="Re-Enter Mobile Number or Email" type="text" id="namebox" /><br>
            <input placeholder="New password" type="text" id="namebox" /><br>
            Birthday<br>
            <input type="date" id="namebox"/><br>
            <input type="radio" id="sex" value="male"/>male
            <input type="radio" id="sex" value="male"/>female<br>
            By clicking Create Account, you agree to our Terms and that you have read our Data Policy, including our Cookie Use. You may receive SMS Notifications from Faceboo and can opt out at any time.<br><br>
            <input type="button" class="button2" value="SUBMIT">
            <hr>Create a Page for a celebrity, band or business.
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
        <p>English(US) Tagalog Bisaya Español 日本語 한국어 中文(简体) العربية Português(Brasil) Français(France) Deutsch</p><br>
        <hr>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Here is my CSS:

```
body{
    background-color: #fff;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.header{
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #3363ff;
    position: fixed;
}
.header #faceboo_logo{
    font-size: 50px;
    color: white;
    top: 25px;
    left: 25px;
    height: 50px;
    width: 200px;
}
.header #form1{
    top: 25px;
    left: 900px;
    height: 50px;
    width: 175px;
}
.header #form2{
    top:25px;
    left: 1080px;
    height: 50px;
    width: 175px;
}
.submit1{
    position: fixed;
    height: 50px
    width :50px;
    left: 1260px;
    top: 45px;
}
.body1{
    top:100px;
    background: #e9ebee;
    width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
    position: fixed;
}
#left_content1{
    font-size: 50px;
    left: 130px;
    width: 500px;
    top: 120px;
    height: 200px;
}

#left_content2{
    font-size: 50px;
    left: 850px;
    width: 320px;
    top: 120px;
    height: 50px;
}
#left_content3{
    font-size: 20px;
    left: 850px;
    top: 170px;
    height: 20px;
    width: 225px;
}

#form3{
    width: 350px;
    height: 22px;
    left: 850px;
    position: absolute;
}
.footer{
    top:600px;
    width: 900px;
    position: fixed;
    align-items: center;
    height: 200px;
    left: 20%;
    word-spacing: 10px;
}
```

btw. this is just for practicing my html and css skill, I'm running out of options

Comment: Take a look at overflow: https://css-tricks.com/the-css-overflow-property/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because of `position:fixed` property on `body1` and `header` classes, if everything is fixed then what will be scrollable.

```
.header{
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #3363ff;
    /*position: fixed;*/
}
.body1{
    /*top:100px;*/
    background: #e9ebee;
    width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
    /*position: fixed;*/
}
```

Update shuold  your css.

Comment: you're right @abhishek pandey instead of using fixed, i changed them to absolute, and its now scrollable every thime i re-size the browser, i really dont know yet when to use fixed and absolute, thank you su much!

Answer (score 1):

Use CSS property overflow: auto for body tag like

```
body{
overflow: auto;
}
```

remove position: fixed from your body1 class and then try to arrange fields

```
.body1 {
background: #e9ebee none repeat scroll 0 0;
height: 500px;
position: fixed;
top: 100px;
width: 100%;}
```

Comment: didnt work, i think this is something about my position. cause i always used position: fixed; or sometimes absolute

Comment: you're right @pooja, its the fixed value that wont let my page scrollable when i resized down my browser